# Dynamic associative Array - list, count, sum, min, max

Tags: php, function, dynamic, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I've got an array with about 40 keys. I'd like to have a small function that returns a summary array.

Right now I've got the following that works:

```
foreach ($all_data as $value){
    $new_array[ $value['location'] ][ $value['manufacturer'] ][ $value['model'] ] += 1;
}
```

This returns an array with everything I need. However, the location, manufacturer and model could be changed up for a bunch of other values.

what I am trying to do is have something simple as:

```
$new_array = summarize($all_data,array('location','manufacturer','model','count'),array('list','list','list','count') );}
```

where this summarize function would build the call. I think I just need a bit of help on how to get it to run the string as code for this array. Otherwise I get

```
$current_selection = "[ $row_item['location'] ][ $row_item['manufacturer'] ][ $row_item['model'] ]"
$return_array{$current_selection} += 1;
```

Where the end goal is to have a function like:

```
function summarize($data_array, $fields_array, $process_array){
    //data_array    = associative multi-dimensional data array
    //fields    = values to pull from the data_array
    //process   = array specifying whether to list, sum, count, average, max, min

$return_array = array();
$current_selection = "";
foreach($fields_array as $field){
    $current_selection .= '[ $row_item[\'' . $field . '\'] ]';
}

    foreach ($data_array as $row_item){

//dynamic = DOES NOT WORK
        $return_array[$current_selection] += 1;//eval? create function? abstract?
        //another attempt
${'return_array' . $current_selection} += 1;
//Manual = Does work
        //$return_array[    $row_item['location']  ][   $row_item['manufacturer']  ][   $row_item['model']  ] += 1;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help on how to do an indirect reference.

JC

**RESOLUTION**
The final version that managed to resolve this looks like the following, thanks to user: check, for getting me on the correct path.

```
function summarize($data_array, $fields_array, $process_array){
    $return_array = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data_array as $row){
    $ii = 0;
        $temp = array();
        $temp2 = array();
        foreach($fields_array as $key=>$field){
            if($process_array[$ii] == 'list')   $temp[$ii] = $row[$field];
        if($process_array[$ii] == 'count')  $temp2[$ii] = 1;
        if($process_array[$ii] == 'sum')    $temp2[$ii] = $row[$field];
        $ii++;
        }

        $unique = true;
        $ii = 0;
        foreach($return_array as $row2){
            if(array_intersect_key($row2,$temp) == $temp){//$row2 == $temp){
                $unique = false;
                break;
            }
            $ii++;
        }

        if($unique){
            $return_array[$i] = $temp;
            if(!empty($temp2)) $return_array[$i] = array_merge($temp,$temp2);
            $i++;
    }else{
        if(!empty($temp2)){
            foreach($temp2 as $key => $value){
                if($process_array[$key] == 'sum')   $temp2[$key] = $return_array[$ii][$key] + $value;
                if($process_array[$key] == 'count') $temp2[$key] = $return_array[$ii][$key] + 1;
                if($process_array[$key] == 'max')   $temp2[$key] = ($return_array[$ii][$key] < $value) ? $value : $return_array[$ii][$key];
                if($process_array[$key] == 'min')   $temp2[$key] = ($return_array[$ii][$key] > $value) ? $value : $return_array[$ii][$key];
                //TODO:(JC) 'average' - need to create a count field if not present (or always despite and assume overhead of extra computations).
                //            - then just calculate the 'sum' and divide by the counter as a last step before returning the array.
            }
            $return_array[$ii] = array_merge($temp,$temp2);
        }
    }
    }
        print_r($return_array);
    return $return_array;
}
```

Which gives the following result:

```
/*
CALL: summarize($data,array('location','manufacturer','model','model','volume','colourvolume'),array('list','list','list','count','sum','sum') );
    [0] = location
    [1] = manufacturer
    [2] = model
    [3] = model count
    [4] = mono volume sum
    [5] = colour volume sum
 */
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => HP
            [2] => LaserJet 4000
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 3000
            [5] => 0
        )
    ...

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => Room 114
            [1] => CANON
            [2] => iR3235
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 4012
            [5] => 0
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => Room 115
            [1] => LEXMARK
            [2] => T652
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 20
            [5] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Please don't put any markers/tags in your question title. Accepting an answer is the way to say you're satisfied with the answer(s) you received. Also you shouldn't post your solution in your question. Post it as an answer if it differs from other answer(s) already posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alternatively, if I assume that's `$field_array` contains sequentially key fields from root to sub key, you can loop your `$field_array` within `$data_array` loop

```
function summarize($data_array, $fields_array, $process_array){
    $return_array = array();
    foreach ($data_array as $row){
        $temp = array();
        foreach($fields_array as $key=>$field){
            $temp = $key==0?$row[$field]:$temp[$field];
        }
        if(!empty($temp)) $return_array[] = $temp;
    }
    return $return_array;
}
```

and this is my array, will summarize with these function

```
$array = array(
    array("multi"=>array("dimensional"=>array("array"=>"foo1"))),
    array("multi"=>array("dimensional"=>array("array"=>"foo2"))),
    array("multi"=>array("dimensional"=>array("array"=>"foo3"))),
    array("multi"=>array("dimensional"=>array("array"=>"foo4"))),
    array("multi"=>array("dimensional"=>array("array"=>"foo5"))),
    array("multi"=>array("dimensional"=>array("array"=>"foo6"))),
    array("multi"=>array("dimensional"=>array("array"=>"foo7"))),
    array("multi"=>array("dimensional"=>array("array"=>"foo8"))),
    array("multi"=>array("dimensional"=>array("array"=>"foo9")))
);
print_r(summarize($array,array("multi","dimensional","array"),NULL));
```

Ouput

```
Array ( [0] => foo1 [1] => foo2 [2] => foo3 [3] => foo4 [4] => foo5 [5] => foo6 [6] => foo7 [7] => foo8 [8] => foo9 )
```